# Access 2010 Controling enter key behavior

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a password form and currently after entering the password pressing enter moves to the next tab location. I would like to make it so pressing enter is equivalent to clicking on the Login Button at the bottom of my form.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
    Private Sub varPassword_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
        If KeyAscii = vbKeyReturn Then
            Me.cmdOK.OnClick
        End If
    End Sub
```

This only works when I press shift + enter. just pressing the enter key causes a move to the next field. Any Ideas

I am aware of the
File -> Options -> Client Settings -> Move after enter
settings and they do not help me.

Any ideas on how I can do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa173447%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property to specify a control's place in the tab order on a form.

Make sure you have the **cmdOK** after the password  box in that order on your form

Also see how to [Make a command button the default button in a form or custom dialog box](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/make-a-command-button-the-default-button-in-a-form-or-custom-dialog-box-HP005187773.aspx)

Comment: Well I guess I was just jumping to code prematurely. I had the Tab index how I wanted it but I didn't know about default buttons. Thanks!

Comment: Also, check out the Cancel property of a command button to connect it to the Escape key.